# editing php page to insert new value to my table

Tags: php, html, mysql, localhost

hey I'm Newbie and want to edit php page and adding some extra code so my problem is
I added new column to my table and I want to send data from new input text to my table to new column
I add the input text and now I wand to insert that data in new column
even I didn't find the insert query to editing it

my code is below

```
<?php include_once 'asset/admin-ajax.php'; ?>
<?php echo message_box('success'); ?>
<?php echo message_box('error'); ?>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="wrap-fpanel">
            <div class="panel panel-default" data-collapsed="0">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <strong><?php echo $this->language->form_heading()[13] ?></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form id="form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/employee/save_employee_award/<?php
                    if (!empty($award_info->employee_award_id)) {
                        echo $award_info->employee_award_id;
                    }
                    ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel_controls">
                            <div class="form-group" id="border-none">
                                <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[14][0] ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <select name="designations_id" class="form-control" onchange="get_employee_by_designations_id(this.value)">                            
                                        <option value="">اختر تعيين.....</option>
                                        <?php if (!empty($all_department_info)): foreach ($all_department_info as $dept_name => $v_department_info) : ?>
                                                <?php if (!empty($v_department_info)): ?>
                                                    <optgroup label="<?php echo $dept_name; ?>">
                                                        <?php foreach ($v_department_info as $designation) : ?>
                                                            <option value="<?php echo $designation->designations_id; ?>" 
                                                            <?php
                                                            if (!empty($award_info->designations_id)) {
                                                                echo $designation->designations_id == $award_info->designations_id ? 'selected' : '';
                                                            }
                                                            ?>><?php echo $designation->designations ?></option>                            
                                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                <?php endif; ?>                            
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" id="border-none">
                                <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[14][1] ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <select name="employee_id" id="employee" class="form-control" >
                                        <option value="">اختر موظف...</option>  
                                        <?php if (!empty($employee_info)): ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($employee_info as $v_employee) : ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $v_employee->employee_id; ?>" 
                                                <?php
                                                if (!empty($award_info->employee_id)) {
                                                    echo $v_employee->employee_id == $award_info->employee_id ? 'selected' : '';
                                                }
                                                ?>><?php echo $v_employee->first_name . ' ' . $v_employee->last_name ?></option>                            
                                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[14][2] ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input type="text" name="award_name" class="form-control" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($award_info->award_name)) {
                                        echo $award_info->award_name;
                                    }
                                    ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> new column <span class="required">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input type="text" name="new_column" class="form-control" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($award_info->new_column)) {
                                        echo $award_info->new_column;
                                    }
                                    ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>




                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[14][3] ?></label>

                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input type="text" name="gift_item" class="form-control" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($award_info->gift_item)) {
                                        echo $award_info->gift_item;
                                    }
                                    ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[14][4] ?></label>

                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input type="text" name="award_amount" class="form-control" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($award_info->award_amount)) {
                                        echo $award_info->award_amount;
                                    }
                                    ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[14][5] ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="award_date" placeholder="ادخل الشهر"  class="form-control monthyear" value="<?php
                                        if (!empty($award_info->award_date)) {
                                            echo $award_info->award_date;
                                        }
                                        ?>" data-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="entypo-calendar"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
                                    <button type="submit" id="sbtn" name="sbtn" value="1" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[1][12] ?></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" data-offset="0">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>
                        <strong><?php echo $this->language->from_body()[14][6] ?></strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Table -->

            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-sm-1">رقم الموظف</th>
                        <th>اسم الموظف</th>
                        <th>اسم المكافئة</th>
                        <th>بند المكافئة</th>
                        <th>مبلغ الكافئة</th>
                        <th>الشهر</th>
                        <th>  : اجراء</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php if (!empty($all_employee_award_info)):foreach ($all_employee_award_info as $v_award_info): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $v_award_info->employment_id ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $v_award_info->first_name . ' ' . $v_award_info->last_name; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $v_award_info->award_name;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $v_award_info->gift_item; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $v_award_info->award_amount;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo date('F y', strtotime($v_award_info->award_date)) ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo btn_edit('admin/employee/employee_award/' . $v_award_info->employee_award_id . '/' . $v_award_info->designations_id); ?>
                                    <?php echo btn_delete('admin/employee/delete_employee_award/' . $v_award_info->employee_award_id); ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                   
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

anyone for help please

Comment: Your question doesn’t make too much sense right now. Are you saying `save_employee_award` is a file? What framework are you using? What have you tried? Have you tired looking in your project folders for that file?

Comment: `<?php echo base_url() . 'admin/employee/save_employee_award/'; exit; ?>` F5 => Copy => paste into a file explorer of your choice.

Comment: Are you saying save_employee_award is a file...? Yes
is it file and where can find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the full path of the file copy paste the code at the top of the file and then you can easily go to the directory where the file is located.

```
<? echo base_url().'admin/employee/save_employee_award/'; exit; ?>
```

Comment: where can i get the path 
I did that and pasted it in top of page and refresh the page but path not appear